# is it possible to match consecutive lines that start with the same word/pattern

Tags: regex

I realize that this is probably not the smartest thing to do with regular expressions but I was wondering if it is possible in theory.

Given a text-file example:

```
MYL3    P08590
MYL3    B2R534
MYL3    Q9NRS8
TM38A   Q9H6F2
TM38A   A8K9P9
TRFE    P02787
TRFE    O43890
TRFE    Q1HBA5
TRFE    Q9NQB8
TRFE    Q9UHV0
ETFA    P13804
KCRM    P06732
KCRM    Q96QL9
```

... would it be possible to match the lines that start with the same pattern as the previous line, just by use of regular expressions? Matching and replacing the lines (that match the criteria) with nothing would be something like:

```
MYL3    P08590
TM38A   Q9H6F2
TRFE    P02787
ETFA    P13804
KCRM    P06732
```

My guess is that even though it is possible to use multiple line matching to check the previous line, it wouldn't be possible to accomplish just by regular expressions, as there is no defined pattern to match but instead just the first (couple of) word(s) in consecutive lines. It would require to define the beginning of a line as a "variable" and to compare the beginning of the next line to that, which as far as I know not possible with regex alone.

A colleague, on the other hand, claimed that it might be possible depending on the implementation of regex. I thought I would ask to the experts here.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?s)(\w+)\s+\w+\r\n(\1\s+\w+(?:\r\n)?)+
```

1. `(?s)` - single line option enabled
2. `(\w+)` - alphanumeric (group 1), one or more repetitions
3. `\s+` - whitespace, one or more repetitions
4. `\w+` - alphanumeric, one or more repetitions
5. `\r\n`
6. `(\1\s+\w+(?:\r\n)?)` - group 2, one or more repetitions: back reference to group 1, whitespace, one or more repetitions, alphanumeric, one or more repetitions, `\r\n` zero ore one

It will match:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however this doesnt seem to work on gedit. I wonder why... Could you elaborate a bit about the different bits of the regex you have given? If I not mistaken the expression above is something like: Group1= one or more word(s), followed by one or more whitespace characters, then one or more word(s), then Group2= whatever was matched in Group1 followed by whitespace(s) and other word(s) with/without CR/LF? Am I on right track?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Kirill. I have tried this on gedit, fraise, and vim but none of them seem to find anything.. (I am not very familiar with vim so I might have missed something, but the other two should be capable of doing regex searches)

Comment: @posdef, Sorry, I use none of them. Check tool: Does it support `(?s)`, `\w`, `\s`, backreference. Does it provide error output?

Comment: \w and \s are supported and functional. I am not sure how to check for (?s). Which program/webservice did you use to check your regex?

Comment: @posdef, I use .NET regex engine. `(?s)` enables singleline option. Also check does your engine support `\1` (backreference) and non-captured group `(?:\r\n)`. If not, you can use `(\r\n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file in vim and do this:

```
/^\(\([A-Z0-9]\+\)\s\+.*\n\2\)\+
```

See if that works. You might want to :set hlsearch so that vim highlights the matched regex as you build it.

Edit:

You can run the following from the command line to do the substitution in vim:

<strike>$ vi -c '%s/^((([A-Z0-9]+)\s+.*)\n\3.*)+/\2/' file.txt</strike>

Sorry for not testing it with your given sample. Here's the substitution pattern that works with the pattern that you give:

```
$ vi -c '%s/\(\(^[A-Z0-9]\+\)\s\+.*\n\)\(\2\s.*\n\)*/\1/' file.txt
```

As for searching for the pattern, I couldn't make it "jump" to the next block of match. It just jumps to the next line (the one with the same start word) until the second last one for each block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however the pattern doesnt match the lines I have intended to. It highlights the first line and the first word of the second line for each entry. In other words 3rd 4th etc lines are ignored. What I am looking for is to leave the first lines for each entry and highlight entire rows of consecutive lines that start with the same pattern. (PS: the substitution didnt work either, nothing had changed in the file, or am I misunderstanding something in vim? Devil's tool, that vim, so damn confusing :))

Comment: The backslashes hurts the eye. You can use \v to tell vim to treat all possible magic characters as magic even when they are not escaped with a backlash so this will work too: %s/\v((^[A-Z0-9]+)\s+.*\n)(\2\s.*\n)*/\1/